# Match and replace regex with modified regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I'm going through a string like so:

```
'@test1 in else',
'@test2 in something',
```

and look only for

```
test1
test2
```

my goal is to have end result of string to look like this:

```
'([@test1])(test1) in else',
'((@test2))(test2) in something',
```

This is what I do but clearly it doesn't work:

```
fileData.replace(/@(\w)+/g, '([' + /@(\w)+/g + '](' + /@(\w)+/g) + ')')
```

I don't understand how can I save the regex that I found and use it in modified version

Comment: You would use $1, $2 and so on... take a look at the documentation at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
const str = `'@test1 in else',
'@test2 in something',`;
var repl = str.replace(/@(\w+)/g, '([@$1])($1)');

console.log(repl);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kWv8P9/1)

**Breakup:**

- `@(\w+)`: Match a text starting with `@` followed by 1+ word charts and capture word chars in capture group #1
- `([@$1])($1)`: Replacement part to place capture text in wrapper brackets twice